# Overriding virtual method inside another class to access its member in c++

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, overriding, virtual-functions

Suppose I have two classes A and B.
Class A is subclass of X with virtual method known as `now_do()` so I can easily override it with class A. However most issues are in class B, so I want to include class A in B and override `now_do()` as `A::now_do(){...}` but its not possible, So how can I do in order to use variables of class B inside `A::now_do(){}`.

Code example (class B):

```
#include "A.cpp"

class B{
 public:
 int a;
 //....
 void A::now_do(){
  cout<<a<<endl;    //Access a member of this class B.
 }

};

//But it works when I put outside B class
//However now I can't access members of class B.
void A::now_do(){
  cout<<a<<endl;    //Can't access a member of this class B.
}
```

Error I get is: ***You cannot define member function A::now_do() within B.***

Comment: Have you declared now_do as virtual in class A.

Comment: `void A::now_do(){`  defines a function now_do in class/namespace A.  And you've put this, in the declaration of B.  get rid of the A:: to make it a function of B

Comment: `int a` is a public member of `B`, so it is accessible from anywhere.

Comment: `B` doesn't inherit from `X` or `A`.

Comment: @UKMonkey, Note that, B is not subclass of A, I just want virtual method of A to be used here in B.

Comment: @HoneyYadav  Yes.

Comment: @WailenB noted - so stop - get out your duck, and explain to it why you're putting an implementation of A::do_now in the class B.  When you've done that, you'll understand what the compiler is complaining about.

Comment: @BoPersson Yeah, everywhere but within class B but problem is how to override virtual method of class A inside B so that I can access that variable.

Comment: @Jarod42, So the possible workaround is only to force class B to inherit A or X?

Comment: No, that's not the actual problem. That's what you think the solution to your actual problem is. You present us with an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Unclear what you want to do...

Comment: @StoryTeller why? I am fairly new to c++

Comment: @UKMonkey, it was struggle to access variables of B inside virtual method of class A without class B being implementing class A. I wanted to reduce number of implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you can't do what you were trying to do in C++ (nor in any other language, I would think): You see, classes A and B don't share instance information. When you instantiate an A, there is no associated instance of B from which you could take an `a` value. Nor can you "stick" your `a` from a B instance into an `A` instance.

If you want to associate instances of A and B, you will probably want to:

1. Have a

   ```
   class AWithB { A instance_of_A; B instance_of_B; };
   ```

   (that's not a good choice of names of course...)
2. Make the `now_do()` a method of `AWithB`, so it can access both information specific to the `A` instance and to the `B` instance

Another alternative would be for class B to inherit from A, and then it could override `now_do()`.

Comment: Ok I will try to do.